# Execute is always called even when CanExecute is false,Is this correct?

Tags: c#

I am using a delegate command .
I have noticed that regardless CanExecute is true or false execute is always called.
Is this correct?
I would have assumed that Execute would have been called only if CanExecute is true.

Could you clarify?

Thanks a lot

EDITED test shows that Save is always called

```
             [TestFixture]
                public class Can_test_a_method_has_been_called_via_relay_command
                {
                    [Test]
                    public void Should_be_able_to_test_that_insert_method_has_been_called_on_repository()
                    {
                        var mock = new Mock<IEmployeeRepository>();
                        var employeeVm = new EmployeeVM(mock.Object) {Age = 19};
                        employeeVm.SaveCommand.Execute(null);
                        mock.Verify(e=>e.Insert(It.IsAny<Employee>()));
                    }
                    [Test]
                    public void Should_be_able_to_test_that_insert_method_has_not_been_called_on_repository()
                    {
                        var mock = new Mock<IEmployeeRepository>();
                        var employeeVm = new EmployeeVM(mock.Object) { Age = 15 };
                        employeeVm.SaveCommand.Execute(null);
                        mock.Verify(e => e.Insert(It.IsAny<Employee>()),Times.Never());
                    }
                }

                public class EmployeeVM:ViewModelBase
                {
                    private readonly IEmployeeRepository _employeeRepository;

                    public EmployeeVM(IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository)
                    {
                        _employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
                    }


                    private bool _hasInserted;
                    public bool HasInserted
                    {
                        get { return _hasInserted; }
                        set
                        {
                            _hasInserted = value;
                            OnPropertyChanged("HasInserted");
                        }
                    }

                    private int _age;
                    public int Age
                    {
                        get { return _age; }
                        set
                        {
                            _age = value;
                            OnPropertyChanged("Age");
                        }
                    }
                    private string _name;
                    public string Name
                    {
                        get { return _name; }
                        set
                        {
                            _name = value;
                            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
                        }
                    }
                    private RelayCommand _saveCommand;
                    public ICommand SaveCommand
                    {
                        get
                        {
                            return _saveCommand ?? (_saveCommand = new RelayCommand(x => Save(), x => CanSave));
                        }
                    }
                    private  bool CanSave
                    {
                        get 
                        {
                            return Age > 18;
                        }
                    }

                    private void Save()
                    {
                        Insert();
                        HasInserted = true;
                    }

                    private void Insert()
                    {
                        _employeeRepository.Insert(new Employee{Age = Age,Name = Name});
                    }
                }

                public interface IEmployeeRepository
                {
                    void Insert(Employee employee);
                }

                public class Employee
                {
                    public string Name { get; set; }
                    public int Age { get; set; }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Which version of the delegate command do you use? It is always possible to call Execute directly - it is only by convention that the WPF framework refrains from it. How do you use the command? Some more info would certainly help :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test methods are not testing what WPF will be doing run-time.

WPF will first determine if CanExecute evaluates to true - if it is not, the Button/MenuItem/InputBinding etc. is disabled and thus cannot be fired.

As I mentioned in my comment - this is only enforced by convention.

Comment: "Only by convention".I see.
Early days in wpf world. 
Let me be clear. If I put some validation in the CanExecute and return to false at runtime the Execute will stll be called.mmmm
is this what you are saying?

Comment: Yes, if you call Execute() manually, your code will fire - WPF will not call Execute from a Button (any class inheriting from CommandBase) if the Command's CanExecute evaluates to false.

The delegate command does not expect this (it expects that the CanExecute evaluates to true. You are of course free to change that behaviour in your own version of delegate command, but the current delegate command behaves like you would expect of an ICommand in WPF.